# Enviar datos a un procedimiento almacenado en sql server desde laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo en mi procedimiento almacenado en sql server el cual recibe los datos y los almacena en una tabla el procedimiento funciona correctamente ejecutandolo de forma manual:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_registrarsalidavehiculo]

    @est_id as int,
    @uni_patente as varchar(10),
    @uni_id as varchar(20),
    @vig_conductor varchar(50),
    @vig_acompanante as varchar(50),
    @vig_destino as varchar(200),
    @vig_salidaKm as numeric(10, 0),
    @vig_observaciones as varchar(200),
    @com_id as int,
    @usu_id_salida as int,
    @vig_tipo as int,
    @vig_dni  as nvarchar(10)

AS
BEGIN

    insert into rrhh.vigilancia(vig_fechaSalida, est_id, uni_patente, uni_id, vig_conductor, vig_acompanante, vig_destino, vig_salidaKm, vig_observaciones, com_id, usu_id_salida, vig_tipo, vig_dni)
    values(Getdate(), @est_id, @uni_patente, @uni_id, @vig_conductor, @vig_acompanante, @vig_destino, @vig_salidaKm, @vig_observaciones, @com_id, @usu_id_salida, @vig_tipo, @vig_dni)

END
```

al momento de intertar enviar los datos a travez de postman para probar mi apirest me devuelve este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este el codigo que tengo en mi archivo de rutas "api.php":

```
Route::resource('vigilancia', 'App\Http\Controllers\Vigilancia\VigilanciaController', ['only'=>['index','store']]);
```

este el codigo de la funcion store que lo que hace es recibir los datos enviados, comprobar los datos de cada campo y llamar al procedemiento almacenado y enviarselos para realice la operacion correspondiente:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $est_id             =   $request->est_id;
        $uni_patente        =   $request->uni_patente;
        $uni_id             =   $request->uni_id;
        $vig_conductor      =   $request->vig_conductor;
        $vig_acompañante    =   $request->vig_acompañante;
        $vig_destino        =   $request->vig_destino;
        $vig_salidaKm       =   $request->vig_salidaKm;
        $vig_observaciones  =   $request->vig_observaciones;
        $com_id             =   $request->com_id;
        $usu_id_salida      =   $request->usu_id_salida;
        $vig_tipo           =   $request->vig_tipo;
        $vig_dni            =   $request->vig_dni;


        $est_id             =   ($est_id   ==  NULL) ? ($est_id   =   0) :   $est_id;
        $uni_patente        =   ($uni_patente   ==  NULL) ? ($uni_patente   =   '') :   $uni_patente;
        $uni_id             =   ($uni_id   ==  NULL) ? ($uni_id   =   '') :   $uni_id;
        $vig_conductor      =   ($vig_conductor   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_conductor   =   '') :   $vig_conductor;
        $vig_acompañante    =   ($vig_acompañante   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_acompañante   =   '') :   $vig_acompañante;
        $vig_destino        =   ($vig_destino   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_destino   =   '') :   $vig_destino;
        $vig_salidaKm       =   ($vig_salidaKm   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_salidaKm   =   0) :   $vig_salidaKm;
        $vig_observaciones  =   ($vig_observaciones   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_observaciones   =   '') :   $vig_observaciones;
        $com_id             =   ($com_id   ==  NULL) ? ($com_id   =   0) :   $com_id;
        $usu_id_salida      =   ($usu_id_salida   ==  NULL) ? ($usu_id_salida   =   0) :   $usu_id_salida;
        $vig_tipo           =   ($vig_tipo   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_tipo   =   0) :   $vig_tipo;
        $vig_dni            =   ($vig_dni   ==  NULL) ? ($vig_dni   =   0) :   $vig_dni;

        DB::select('EXEC sp_registrarsalidavehiculo (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
                                                        [
                                                            $est_id,           
                                                            $uni_patente,      
                                                            $uni_id,           
                                                            $vig_conductor,    
                                                            $vig_acompañante,  
                                                            $vig_destino,      
                                                            $vig_salidaKm,     
                                                            $vig_observaciones,
                                                            $com_id,           
                                                            $usu_id_salida,    
                                                            $vig_tipo,         
                                                            $vig_dni          
                                                        ]);
}
```

ya probe la funcion index que tambien convoca a un procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos el cual me devuelve una vista y este si funciona, al parecer el problema es con el metodo post por alguna razon

Comment: En la imagen de POSTMAN se aprecia un exec sp_registravehiculo y los parámetros, pero estos se ven todos como si fueran ints y no cadenas tipo 'nada' que le corresponderían a todos los varchar y nvarchar

Comment: entonces tengo que especificar en postman el tipo de valor de cada variable?

Comment: El error te esta mandando a la **linea 703 del Connection.php** deberías empezar a revisar por ahí, quizás no has configurado bien.

Comment: esto es lo que tengo en la linea 703 del connection.php, seria "throw new QueryException(", la verdad no entiendo, creo que ahi es donde hace la consulta a la base de datos

protected function runQueryCallback($query, $bindings, Closure $callback)
    {
        try {
            return $callback($query, $bindings);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new QueryException(
                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
        }
    }

Comment: Tenés variables que no son de tipo entero como $vig_observaciones muy probablemente requieran ir entre comillas ('') y en este caso como tenés una consulta preparada los parámetros sea como '?'